# CultureInfo.ToString vs CultureInfo.CompareInfo.Name in dotnet

Tags: .net, locale

0

I want to fetch locale name including sort-variant (e.g. es-ES_tradnl and es-ES as 2 different locale names) from cultureInfo object.

What should be the best approach to fetch that?

CultureInfo.ToString() or CultureInfo.CompareInfo.Name?

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.name?view=net-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.tostring?view=net-7.0